# SQL query 'not in' clause execution takes too long

Tags: sql

the following query takes too much time, most likely because of a 'not in' use.

Can you suggest any improvement ?

```
SELECT vcode, 
       vname, 
       1014 AS fid 
FROM   testcodes co 
WHERE  co.vcode NOT IN (SELECT dict.vcode 
                        FROM   datadictionary dict 
                        WHERE  dict.fid = 1014)
```

one thing about structure is .
vCode,vName is varchar
and testCodes and DataDictionary have same structure.

I searched this problem and found that the left join can possibly resolve this? (WHY does it do better and how can it be done)?

can someone guide if it can be improved ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT vcode, 
       vname, 
       1014 AS fid 
FROM   testcodes co 
       LEFT JOIN datadictionary dict 
         ON co.vcode = dict.vcode 
            AND dict.fid = 1014 
WHERE  dict.vcode IS NULL
```

You need to have indexes created on:

- (testcodes.vcode)
- (datadictionary.vcode,datadictionary.fid)

Both do a single index scan on each table, but the IN has a Merge Join and the INNER JOIN has a Hash Match.

Comment: As for why it's faster:  the `LEFT JOIN` syntax is a more direct way of telling the query optimizer how to join the tables, whereas `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` is more flexible but requires more work from the database engine.

Comment: Even without indexes. Query ran DAMN FAST. The query i wrote took more than a minute even for merely a few thousand records (almost 10K in data dictionary and 3K in testcodes)

Comment: And by the way, Thanks for such editing too, I always confuse how to indent those sql scripts :)

Comment: Don't ignore the indexes, never do. Add them there, they belong there.

Answer (score 1):

If dict.fid is a unique key (sounds so), then your query should be equivalent to

```
WHERE  co.vcode != (SELECT dict.vcode -- ...
```

co.vcode and dict.vcode might need an index to speed things up.

This answer is not an attempt to give a better hint than Pentium10, more a sidenote.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks OK.
Try add the following indexes
datadictionary Index (fid,vcode)
testCodes Index (vcode)

Comment: The query is not ok, as it doesn't use indexes in optimized way.

Comment: Not sure I agree, The original query with the indexes I listed would do an index seek on both datadictionary and testcodes which bacically means the DB engine never touches records that are not required. Yours will do a full index scan on both tables touching every entry in each index. To me less disk activity is almost always faster. I am interested in which will be faster :)

Comment: That depends by the database engine MSSQL, MySQL, SQLite or Postgres. Anyway using JOINS are faster on every platform than sub-selects.